# Perl, Minus 8 from every value in column 2 in a text file

Tags: perl, output

This works on the first column.  How could I change it to work on just the second?  Can I still do it in one line or would I have to expand it into a .pl file?

Columns are seperated by a comma space ", "

```
perl -pe 's/^([-0-9]+)/$1 - 8/e' your_file > output.txt
```

Details:

- -p reads file line by line and prints it
- -e runs perl code with line content in $_
- s/.../.../e - replace regexp by expression
- ...^([-0-9]+) - matched any digit and/or - sign. Also captures matched fragment.
- $1 - 4.91 - does the work using value captured by regexp.

File example.

```
Title1, Title2, Title3, ..., Titlen

12456, 45, 21, 686731, ...

21, 6876546, 987, 134561, ...
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your input file?  It would be helpful to understand the 'columns' a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your File example the fields are delimited with commas and spaces. It is a bit unusual to have both at the same time. But assuming that this is exactly what you are dealing with, the following modification to your oneliner works:

`perl -pe '/^([-0-9]+), ([-0-9]+)/; $new = $2 - 8; s/^([-0-9]+), ([-0-9]+)/$1, $new/;'`

The first regular expression matches the first and the second fields (when they consist of numbers and -). Then we do the calculation outside of the regular expression syntax, and finally we substitute the second field with the newly calculated value.

Comment: What would it look like if you wanted to do this in a .pl?

Comment: I would try to make the .pl to be more defensive than oneliners usually are, and also try to set up the code to make future changes less painful. I think that the approach proposed by Josh would work nicely: splitting the string into the array is going to allow checking whether the lines are of expected form and length. For example, if we expect at least 3 fields then scalar(@a) has to be >= 3. Also, in if in the future you decide that we want to subtract from the 100th field, all it is going to take is to change $a[1] = $a[1] - 8 into $a[99] = $a[99] - 8.

Comment: @johnstamos you can use perl itself to dump the program equivalent to a oneliner `perl -MO=Deparse -pe '/^([-0-9]+), ([-0-9]+)/; $new = $2 - 8; s/^([-0-9]+), ([-0-9]+)/$1, $new/;'`

Answer (score 3):

While perl gurus are thinking about the answer, here is the awk solution:

```
> echo '5 10 15\n20 25 30' | awk '{$2-=8; print}'
5 2 15
20 17 30
```

**Update**

Let's say you have a file `x.txt` which has the same formatting as your example file:

```
> cat x.txt
t1, t2, t3
1, 12, 3
-4, 22, 13
```

With this command, you can subtract 8 from each numeric field in the second column:

```
> awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {if ($2+0==$2) {$2-=8}; print}' x.txt > output.txt

> cat output.txt
t1, t2, t3
1,4, 3
-4,14, 13
```

Here `-F,` and `BEGIN {OFS=","}` tell awk to use comma as input/output field separators. The next block in curly parentheses will be evaluated for each input line. Thus, for each input line we test if the second field is a number (`$2+0==$2`) and if so, subtract 8 from it, and print the resulting line. The input file is x.txt, and the output will be redirected from standard output to the file `output.txt`.

Comment: Need it to be from a file.

Answer (score 2):

In this example the string is tokenized into an array.  The regex version would be a bit shorter (like the awk).
It also skips the -8 on non strings.

```
perl -ne '@a = split /,\s+/, $_; if($a[1] =~ /^\d*$/) {$a[1] = $a[1] - 8}; print join ", ", @a;'  foo


cat foo 
Title1, Title2, Title3
12456, 45, 21, 68673
21, 6876546, 987, 134561

perl -ne '@a = split /,\s+/, $_; if($a[1] =~ /^\d*$/) {$a[1] = $a[1] - 8}; print join ", ", @a;'  foo
Title1, Title2, Title3
12456, 37, 21, 68673
21, 6876538, 987, 134561
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, Can you explain why you use 2 perl lines and what is happening in the middle cat?  Could you also pipe this to an output.txt doing it this way?

Comment: You can use the `-a` flag to autosplit.

Comment: The string is split up, the 8 is subtracted if it detects a number, then the  data is re-joined and printed.  Add the '> file' to redirect output to a file. The autosplit is a great suggestion! I forget about that one...

Answer (score 0):

Very close to your original while allowing you to modify an arbitrary column:

```
perl -aF',\s*' -pe '$F[1] =~ s/^([-0-9]+)/$1 - 8/e; $_ = join(", ", @F);' file
```

- `-a` autosplit to `@F`
- `-F` on `/,\s*/`
- `$F[1] =~ s/^([-0-9]+)/$1 - 8/e;`  substitute on 2nd column
- `$_ = join(", ", @F);`  rejoin `@F` into `$_` to allow `-p` to print